# Close questions as no longer relevant

Tags: discussion, moderation

I came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882659/super-and-arrow-key-has-started-switching-tty) today.  It's marked as off-topic because:

> "This describes a problem that can't be reproduced that seemingly went
>   away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of
>   time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers."

Given how many of our questions deal with a bug that's since been fixed, I'm wondering if we should do the same?

Comment: Another reason for closing questions is that they are so old as not be ever likely to get any answers and its distracting for the bot to be reposting them.  e.g, Tyring to Upgrade to civicrm 4.7.28 on Joomla but wsod error says civicrm.settings.php is missing https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21899/tyring-to-upgrade-to-civicrm-4-7-28-on-joomla-but-wsod-error-says-civicrm-settin

Answer (score 2):

Interesting idea.  An 'obsolete' category might be preferable since a bug-related question may not have been 'off-topic' at the time it was asked.  Unfortunately SE only gives us 'duplicate', 'off-topic', 'unclear', 'too broad' and 'opinion based' so 'off-topic' may be the best available choice.

Comment: Hey Aidan! You mods actually can set custom off topic reasons for your site (up to three of them) by visiting [this page](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/admin/flags/close-as-off-topic) or by going to the closing>off topic interface on any question (there's a link that says "edit these reasons" in tiny text). If you want some help with this, feel free to ping me and we can help you get it set up. If you'd like such a close reason, use this discussion question to draft the text you want to use and we can go from there.

Comment: Hi Aidan - I almost asked an identical question just now, and it pointed me here.  Could we implement this?  When you're looking for solutions, top answers shouldn't include someone's site-specific issue from 2015. Even a legit bug that was fixed in 2015 should be closed IMO.

Comment: Hi @JonG-MegaphoneTech - I've added an 'obsolete' - please take a look and let me know if you have any suggestions for improving the wording.

Comment: @Aidan I'm not seeing it?